# How to get specific episode from iTunes API?

Tags: web-services, itunes

How do I get a link to a specific episode of a TV show in the iTunes store? I have the name of the show*, the season, and episode number. From the [documentation](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html), I've found that I can get a list of episodes, and then parse the JSON to find the episode and its iTunes links.

However, the documentation also says that one should avoid making too many or too big requests (e.g. by using the limit parameter), so I'm wondering if there is a better way to directly get the desired episode link, without fetching and parsing a potentially huge list of episodes.

---

*) In case the season name is ambiguous, I have the TVDB data, and can also specify a 'canonical' name if neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

The Search API has a few parameters that will help qualify the content you want returned.

It sounds like you should be using the Show title as the "term".

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Jersey+Shore&attribute=tvSeasonTerm&entity=tvEpisode

Adding "attribute=tvSeason" will ensure the term is matched only to TV Show titles and not any other meta data in the iTunes store (including music, movies, apps etc.).

Also, appending "entity=tvEpisode" will indicate to the API that you want only Episodes returned and not just the Season info (by default).